# Want to share a Machine using VNC client

Tags: windows, vnc

I want to access a windows machine using browser, so I have installed Tight VNC, kanaka-NoVNC on my machine.

I want to access all users on different port of no VNC, so now one have access to other's data.

I tried it with but I am not able to access unique session. What I will do for unique session for all users.

I have started 6080 port in administrator account and 6081 port in admin account. When I tried using different url, it shows me same UI. So I would like to change to its UI, not shared UI.

So how can I accomplish it.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a windows machine, you need a version of windows that supports multiple terminal services sessions.  So, you need a version of windows that is higher than Professional.  You need the lowest level of the "server edition" of windows in order to have multiple sessions.   If you cant afford it, then use Linux.    Also, if your on windows, you might want your users to use Bitvise WinSSHd  and Tunnelier client.

Comment: I want to access windows machine using browser ONLY

Answer (score 4):

VNC is all about desktop sharing, it simply isn't designed to do what you want to do.this is nothing to do with port numbers - the product doesn't do what you want.

If this is a windows server then you might want to take a look at terminal services

Comment: I want to access windows machine using browser ONLY

Comment: that can be done

Comment: then you want a browser based terminal services client as well as a terminal services server. There are a few out there but as I don't use them myself I can't really make any suggestions. We used to use Ericom's products which did ok, but its been a while so I don't know where they are right now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to run multiple VNC sessions concurrently, with each user having their own screen. That's not possible. VNC will display the currently logged on user's screen only. As already stated, you need Terminal Services to achieve what you are after and that requires a server operating system.